# How to model an action that involves more than one model?

Tags: domain-driven-design, domain-model, repository, service

I'd like to start by saying that I'm new to DDD and I'm creating a hobby system to practice some concepts, so this question might be trivial, but not so much for me.

I have the following scenario:

I have a given user that should be able to add exercise to the system, so I have two models `User` and `Exercise`, and I have a method `addExercise` which should create a new exercise and save it to database by using a repository. This method would mostly validate `Exercise` data before saving to database, but there would be some validations regarding the user (such as verify if exercise wasn't previously created by this user)

I have thought about three ways to do that:

1. Add an `addExercise` method to User model. Problems I see in this approach:

   a) `User` model would need to know about `Exercise` in order to implement `addExercise`.

   b) `User` model would need a repository to save the `Exercise` in database.
2. Add an `addExercise` method to `UserService`, since adding exercise is an operation from user, this seems ok, but when I start thinking about implementation, I would have `UserService` to know about `Exercise` and `ExerciseRepository`.
3. Add an `addExercise` method to `ExerciseService`, which I believe it is fine, but I'm afraid I might be missing something.

So, in my opinion, from a business point of view, `addExercise` should be a method in `User` model, but when I think about implementation details, it seems to make more sense option 3), but I want to know if this is in fact the correct option.

Also, I have some other questions:

I) Is it normal for a given model A to be able to create another model B or have a repository from a model B inside of it ? Or could a model A receive a repository that work with model A ?

II) Is it ok for a service A to receive repositories that work with model B ?

Comment: Maybe you’re missing a concept. You say a user should be able to add an exercise to *the system* but perhaps you can make that more explicit. Model the relation between user and exercise.

Comment: Btw *user* is a bad name imo. In the ubiquitous language, what do you call a person who has some relationship with exercises? An *athlete* perhaps?

Comment: There are other models in the system, there is a Routine model where it is possible to add exercises, however, the exercises to be added in a routine should be created by the user/athlete. And actually, creating a routine falls in the same problem as described in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use your third option. In systems with users basically everything is user focused, but putting that functionality in a user model doesn't make sense in most cases. If exercise is a domain model you want, then the ability to add one 100% belongs to the exercise domain/service. The reason for this is because a domain model should be responsible for creating/updating itself. If exercise requires a reference to user that's fine, DDD allows for models to reference other models. The best practice is basically using the same concept as foreign keys in a database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now that you mentioned, I wonder if having Exercise as a model makes sense. I have two other models, Workout and Routine, a Routine is made of several workouts and day to train and a workout is made of several exercises and sets and reps for each exercise. Both Routine and Workout have few attributes on its own, it seems more like a hybrid between aggregate and a model, I will definitely need Exercise, but I'm not sure if it is a model since it seems to have very little behavior, the same could be said about a Workout. The user should deal only with Routine.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the user can create Workout and Routine and add Exercise to the system, so it is not exactly dealing only with a Routine, however, it all seems to be only CRUD operations, there is very few logic in these models, I wonder if I'm using the correct approach for this problem, since the models are probably going to be very anemic.